# Did Powerless use Adam West’s voice?

Tags: voice-acting, powerless

It sounds like Adam West did the voice over at the beginning of *Powerless*, but he’s not credited.  I didn’t find anyone else listed for that part, so who was it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, he was. From the official trailer. Note he's named in the title.

Comment: The video seems to be "private" and thus inaccessible. Is that only a local thing or does it actually not work at all?

Comment: @NapoleonWilson It worked last night when I saw it here... now it's gone.